# How do I force install a .run?

Tags: command-line

Trying to install my ATI driver, and it's not letting me, how would I force a .run to install?

Comment: Not related to your question but I'd like to be sure this installation is necessary. The default driver install didn't work?

Comment: Provide the errrormessage here, as text. You don't need screenshots. Mark the text with the mouse, and paste it with the middle button (wheel) into a textfield. If you need to use screenshots elsewhere, use the image-button in the textfield, and show the image embedded.

Answer (score 2):

Run these commands

```
# Make it executable
chmod a+x *.run

# Run it as root
sudo ./*.run
```

Change *.run to the name of the file (use tab completion).

Post any error message you get.

Comment: http://thecybershocker.com/img/?v=7LQw.png I see that, and keep seeing that :(

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Br9keKjz is what's in the .log file

Comment: That error seems to indicate you already have a driver installed. You will have to remove the old driver first. Did you install it from the software center ?

Comment: Nope, didn't even install any drivers I don't think, fresh install, with all the updates done. :O

Answer (score 1):

right click the file... click on properties.
click on permissions tab.
click on allow executing file as a program.
click close.
double click on the file.
click on run in terminal.